# PGFPlots: Missing minor ticks at the end of axes

Tags: pgfplots

In the following MWE the minor ticks are not drawn to the end of the axes but stop at last major tick (at x=1.5 and at y=100).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat = 1.15,
    minor tick num = 4
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot
            table {
                x   y
                0.0 100
                1.5 10
            };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: missing minor ticks]

Could this be due to a bug in the `pgfplots` package? How could I force the minor ticks to be drawn to the end of the axes?

EDIT: The minor ticks are drawn as expected using version 1.14 of `pgfplots`. (I installed version 1.14, just setting `compat = 1.14` did not work.)

Comment: Please consider accepting the provided answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Help `pgfplots` by providing the **axes limits**, e. g.
>   `\begin{axis}[ymax = 110]`. Not in every diagram you want the ticks to
>   be drawn to the very end of the axes.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat = 1.15,
    minor tick num = 4
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [
        ymax = 110,
        ]
        \addplot
            table {
                x   y
                0.0 100
                1.5 10
            };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Have a look at the **manual** for more information.

[image]

Comment: @torbjørn-t (https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%C3%B8rn-t) Did you edit the answer? I edited it the same time and now don't know what you indented.

Comment: As you can see from the [revision history](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/386209/revisions), I only removed the quote formatting (`>` at beginning of line) for the first paragraph of text. It's not a quote, so I don't understand why you used it.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I see. I just like the appearance. I sometimes see others (mis)use the quote to highlight something.

Comment: Well, I'm not going to go into an editing war with you, but I do think it's wrong, and would suggest that you don't use it like that. (But that's just my opinion.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint! It works. Since I have quite a large number of pgfplots in my document, setting all axis limits manually is a bit cumbersome. Do you have an idea how I could help `pgfplots` to set the limits more generally? At the moment I do this with the `enlargelimits` key and its variants.

Comment: @luki Going to bed now. :) But I think that your question has an answer now that you can accept. Ask a new question if there is another question.